# Efficient Way of Coding Java ResultSet

Tags: java, resultset

I have about 40 web services and for each, I have the following code to get the results from the database. At most, I only retrieve about 200 rows from the database, many times way less than that. However, I was told by a fellow developer that this code is not very efficient, especially the `getColumnName` method, which is expensive. I just thought I'd use `getColumnName` as a key because it's descriptive. Is there a more efficient way of doing the same thing as below? If so, how can I make this more efficient? Any design patterns I should look into to make this better? Thanks in advance.

```
 try{
       ...
        //Open Db Connection
       ...
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QueryClass.getQuery());
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        while(rs.next()){
         HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(columnCount);
          for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
            map.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), rsmd.getObject(i));

        }

        //add to arraylist
        list.add(map);
        }
} catch(SQLException e){
  .....

}
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked and seen a performance problem?

Comment: Yes, I benchmarked, but I didn't see a performance problem. Given my peer's comment, I thought there would be a better way to write this. When I asked her why she thought it was inefficient, and how I could make this better, she wouldn't really give me an answer.

Comment: So you've proven her wrong, and the lack of an answer indicates that she doesn't know what she's talking about. The column name is returned as part of the query result: that's why it's available. Don't worry about this. The database operations and network traffic completely dominate the running time here.

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not seeing a performance issue then there's really no need to change your code for efficiency reasons alone. If the structure you are using makes sense to you then you should stick with it.

There are a few other options you might want to consider:

1. Have a separate list of column names that you store once:

   `List<String> columnNames;`

   `List<List<Object>> rowData;`
2. Record the data by column rather than by row:

   `Map<String, List<Object>> columnData;`
3. Encapsulate the queries by defining an interface that can be implemented using a method appropriate to the table, allowing you to change the implementation if you have a performance issue without changing the interface.

For example:

```
public interface Table {
    List<String> getColumnNames();
    Object getValue(String column, int row);
}
```